# add hyperlink in datatable R

Tags: r, datatable

```
df <- data.frame(
  URL = c("https://drive.google.com/file/d/12345/edit", "https://drive.google.com/file/d/67890/edit"),
  nama_file = c("file1", "file2")
)

df$URL <- sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', df$URL, df$URL)
datatable(df, 
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(targets = 1, visible = FALSE)), 
    dom = 't',
    pageLength = 10 
  )
) %>%
  formatStyle(
    'URL',
    target = '_blank',
    style =  function(value) {
      htmltools::tags$a(href = value, target="_blank", style = "color: blue; text-decoration: underline;", "Klik disini")
    }
  )
```

In the example above, the value from the URL field is converted into a hyperlink using the sprintf() function with the format %s, which will generate a hyperlink with the same URL as the value of the URL field and the same label. is equal to the value of the URL column. Furthermore, in the datatable() function, the original URL column is hidden and in the formatStyle() function, the URL column value is changed to a hyperlink and given a CSS style so that when clicked, it will open the hyperlink in a new tab.

but when i run the code i get this error message

```
Error in paste(s, collapse = "\n") :
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```